# Fix aspect ratio of a monitor from ubuntu

Tags: monitor

I do have a BenQ GL2580 monitor. It does use 16:9 input.
Sadly, its physical aspect ratio does not match 16:9. A perfect square is slightly stretched. Because of this issue, this monitor does not work for my 3D modelling workflow.

There is no way to fix the stretching directly in the monitor.

Do you know if there is a way to fix aspect ratio by scaling the whole screen (in x-direction or y-direction) by a small fraction? Something I could do on Ubuntu to force the monitor to display a square as a square.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you do some modelling you must have a graphics card and hence its driver and its proprietary software installed like ServerX for Nvidia.

[image]

So you may check this interface to find the setting you may have to change

And for the case that you might not have a dedicated graphics card just go over to settings but you may not get enough options there.

[image]

Here you will see the settings for custom resolutions etc

Thanks for asking!